# Properly reference a (javascript) jquery plugin inside my typescript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, aurelia

I would like to use a jquery plugin inside a typescript page of my [Aurelia](https://aurelia.io/) SPA. This plugin is called [morelines](https://github.com/tsurule/morelines)

Here is my current solution so far:

my typescript file: **post.ts**

```
import './jquery.morelines'
export class Post {
    attached() {
            $('.card__description--details').moreLines({
                linecount: 6,
                baseclass: 'b-description',
                basejsclass: 'js-description',
                classspecific: '_readmore',
                buttontxtmore: "",
                buttontxtless: "",
                animationspeed: 400
            });
    }
}
```

the plugin **jquery.morelines.js**

[Code visible here on github](https://github.com/tsurule/morelines/blob/master/jquery.morelines.js)

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.moreLines = function (options) {
      ...
    }
 }(jQuery));
```

my **tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "amd",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

It works at runtime but I got errors when bundling ( `au build`)

[image]

[image]

How to get rid of these errors ? How to properly reference this javascript jquery plugin inside my typescript file ?

Comment: Have you read the docs on how to instgrate old libs? https://aurelia.io/docs/cli/cli-bundler/dependency-management#prepend

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it by simply adding a reference to my jquery plugin like below:

aurelia.json

```
"dependencies": [
    ...
    ...
    {
        "name": "jquery.morelines",
        "path": "../javascript",
        "main": "jquery.morelines",
        "deps": [
          "jquery"
        ]
    }
]
```

No need to add any `import` in my typescript page.

posts.ts

```
    ...
    (<any>$('.card__description--details')).moreLines({
      linecount: 6,
      baseclass: 'b-description',
      basejsclass: 'js-description',
      classspecific: '_readmore',
      buttontxtmore: "",
      buttontxtless: "",
      animationspeed: 400
    });
```